# Missing icon for "Show desktop" in Dash in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-dash

I upgraded today to 18.04. One item I am missing is a "Show desktop" button in the dash. How can I add this without running a script?  (This must be a common request)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to use/install a relevant gnome extension.
There is for example https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1194/show-desktop-button/ however this adds a button to the top bar.
Alternatively, you could install gnome-tweak-tool to check if the ubuntu dock extension has an otion for this. Or, you could try the das-to-panel extension (instead of the ubuntu dock, probably) that has a option for this.

Answer (score 0):

The most useful solution for me was always to bind the same keyboard shortcut to "Show desktop" as in Windows. This way, whatever OS I use, I always press the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut (<kbd>Super</kbd> is the key with Windows logo).

Achieving this in GNOME is as simple as running command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop ['<Super>d']
```

To achieve the same without using console, open System Settings, go to Devices, Keyboard and adjust there a shortcut for '*Hide all normal windows*'.

Additionally, if you sometimes use a mouse, I find the [TaskBar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/) GNOME extension very handy. By default it displays a nice blue icon to show a desktop on the top panel:
[image].